# MySQL statement that only returns rows by id where a name appears a majority of the time

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, having-clause

Table `t1`

```
id | name
_________
1  | ann
1  | joe
1  | joe

2  | ann
2  | ann
2  | joe
2  | joe

3  | ted
3  | ann
3  | joe

4  | bob
4  | bob
4  | bob
4  | ted
```

MySQL statement that only returns ID's where the name appears a majority of the time,

```
id
__
1
4
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't return any results,

```
SELECT `id` FROM `t1` GROUP BY `id` having max(name) > 0.5 * max(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select id, name
from (select id, name, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by id) as id_cnt
      from t
      group by id, name
     ) ni
where cnt > 0.5 * id_cnt;
```